# How to use ng-style while geting style from json

Tags: angularjs, ng-style

[Here is my code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXNRbB)

This is my code `ng-style="background: {{x.background}}"`

What renders `ng-style="background: #f4f4f4"`

I am expecting `style="background: #f4f4f4"`

Comment: Always post relevant code at StackOverflow. People don't generally care if you 'link' to other websites. Please check [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information about formatting your code on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct directive is `ng-attr-style`, check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ng-style="{ background: x.background}"
```

This much more closely resembles json. In fact you can have a json object and use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
ng-style="background: {{x.background}}"
```

into

```
ng-attr-style="background: {{x.background}}"
```